# Error in SQL Syntax use near '06:09:43 WHERE Book_id = 19 AND Date_issued = 2017-03-29 17:28:34' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

> ERROR: Could not able to execute You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '06:09:43 WHERE Book_id = 19 AND
>   Date_issued = 2017-03-29 17:28:34' at line 1

I've been getting the above error upon executing the following code -

```
if(isset($_GET['rt']))//rt is a variable I'm passing in an anchor tag
{
$dateis=$_GET['rt'];
}
if(isset($_GET['id']))//id is also sent along with rt
{
$bk_id=$_GET['id'];
}
$ret = 'returned successfully';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE issued_books SET Date_returned = $date WHERE Book_id = $bk_id AND Date_issued = $dateis"))
{
    $fine = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATEDIFF('$dateis', '$date') AS days");
    $fine = $fine*10;
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE issued_books SET Fine_amt = (Fine_amt + $fine) WHERE Date_issued = $dateis");
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE library_books SET Available = (Available + 1) WHERE Book_id = $bk_id");
    header("Location: return-books.php?book=".urlencode($ret));
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute " .mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Strings need to be encapsulated in quotes. Use prepared statements and the driver will handle quoting/escaping for you. You are open to SQL injections with your current code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first update query use `'` single quotes here

```
 Date_returned = '$date'
```

I also suggest to use pdo

Comment: @ParvezKhan : If it worked accept this ans by clicking green tick mark. Also please consider to convert code into pdo.

Comment: @Niklesh Let OP choose whether he want to use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Try these, just add single quotes to variables

```
"UPDATE issued_books SET Date_returned = '$date' WHERE Book_id = '$bk_id' AND Date_issued = '$dateis'"

"UPDATE issued_books SET Fine_amt = (Fine_amt + '$fine') WHERE Date_issued = '$dateis'"

"UPDATE library_books SET Available = (Available + 1) WHERE Book_id = '$bk_id'"
```

Although it would be better if you use prepared statements.

Comment: There are other ways to include variables directly into a query, one is enclosing them into a single quote

Comment: What does this mean - near '06:09:43